# Daily block report from assp for each mail user

Tags: email, email-server, assp

I want to automatically send daily block report from assp to each mail user.

I've set the `BlockReportFile` parameter as: `file:files/blockreportlist.txt`

My `blockreportlist.txt` has the following records:

```
user1@mydomain.com=>user1@mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com=>user2@mydomain.com
```

But it doesn't work when I check "`Generate a BlockReport from BlockReportFile Now (BlockReportNow)`" and click "`Run now!`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my `blockreportlist.txt` to:

```
*@mydomain.com
```

Now, It works.